# How can i make shoe patterns in alphabets in Adobe like following image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, typography

[image]

I want to design this poster but couldn't figure out how can I make shoe designs inside alphabets and change color texture in alphabets?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and why it is failing.

Comment: Instead of adjusting the shape of existing alphabetic characters, look at your example again and consider taking a texture block and create the characters themselves by “cutting” shoe shapes out of the texture.

Comment: Is Adobe a software or place?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - ***Please*** look through **[tour]** to get a sense of what our community is about; *then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a **good** query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ask that questions show ***effort*** - show us *what you've tried*. We *also* have a ***strong*** preference against questions which appear to be requests for free work or step-by-=step tutorials on demand; yours seems perilously close to that as currently framed. Please read [ask] and revise your question to better fit our guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find or draw a silhouette of a shoe, and use the path finder Minus Front to subtract it from a shape.

[image]

Use the finished letter shape as a clipping mask on top of a raster image. Select both, then do *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

[image]